# Modal Panel with rounded corners

Tags: swift, cocoa, modal-dialog

I'm wondering if there is a way to display a modal window with rounded corners instead of the default sharp corners. The image shows what corners I'm referring to.

[image]

I tried with changing the `contentView.layer?.cornerRadius` but it didn't work. What can I do to get the result I need?

Comment: You don't want to do that.  Even if you succeeded, the shadow around the rectangular window would remain.

Comment: if so, I want also to delete the shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working a lot on it, I finally found a solution:

Frist create a new borderless window in your interface builder. Place a custom box in that view and make sure it leaves a bit of space from the top border of the window:

[image]

Then add an outlet of that window object in your app delegate:

```
@IBOutlet weak var saveWindow: NSWindow!
```

So copy that extension for loading and dismissing a panel as a modal sheet:

```
extension NSWindow {

    public func loadPanel(named: NSWindow) {
        named.isOpaque = false
        named.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        named.hasShadow = false
        self.beginSheet(named, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    public func closePanel(named: NSWindow) {
        self.endSheet(named)
    }

}
```

You just need to call this two functions if you want to open a panel.

```
window.loadPanel(named: saveWindow)
```

And when you're done:

```
window.closePanel(named: saveWindow)
```

This is the result:

[image]